# upload csv to mysql as background in php

Tags: php, file-upload, background

I upload the csv file by the help of JQuery but the problem is until the completion of that job,I can't do anything means if I leave the page, the process will be stop.That's why I want to know that-
How to upload csv file into MySQL as background in php. At first, I upload the file from local machine to server then insert the file into MySQL database

In Java or C# it is easy for thread concept. but in PHP has no thread concept.

Comment: till uploading the csv you cannot do anything even with thread !

Comment: i want to do that after completing the upload

Comment: have you tried upload using shell ?

Comment: shell means.  I watch a code in internet but there they told that the background job is possible on linux OS. But I want to do that on window OS

Comment: Windows has that feature as well . check http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background

Comment: ok, but how to use it at my program

Comment: you can do that in php with shell_exec().check http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/to-run-php-code-in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

// fileuploader.php (is at C:xampp/htdocs)

```
$filename = “C:xampp/htdocs/file.xls”; // file to be uploaded
$destination=“www.xyz.com/destination”;
$isUploaded     = move_uploaded_file ( $filename , $destination ); // will upload the file

if($isUploaded) {
    // do the stuffs for writing the content to database
}
```

Now you have to run this file from windows task scheduler OR you can write a bash/shell script for executing the fileuploader.php in certain interval of time (once in a day or once in a minute )

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question - how to do it in PHP as a background process.  If it can't be done, say so.